# Why does an encrypted byte array have a different length from its char[] representation?

Tags: c#, encryption

I was working on some encryption/decryption algorithms and I noticed that the encrypted byte[] arrays always had a length of 33, and the char[] arrays always had a length of 44.  Does anyone know why this is?

(I'm using Rijndael encryption.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Padding](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cryptopad.html) and [text encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding).  Most encryption algorithms have a block size, and input needs to be padded up to a multiple of that block size.  Also, turning binary data into text usually involves the [Base64 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which expands 3 bytes into 4 characters.

Comment: So it's a property of Base64!  That explains a lot.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

That's certainly not true for all encryption algorithms, it must just be a property of the particular one you're using. Without knowing what algorithm it is, I can only guess, but the ratio 33/44 suggests that the algorithm might be compressing each character into 6 bits in the output byte array. That probably means it's making the assumption that no more than 64 distinct characters are used, which is a good assumption for plain text (in fact, that's how base64 decoding works).

But again, without knowing what algorithm you're using, this is all guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the encryption you're using, its a little tough to determine the exact cause.  To start, here's an article on [How to Calculate the Size of Encrypted Data](https://web.archive.org/web/20120904015607/http://www.obviex.com/Articles/CiphertextSize.aspx).  It sounds like you might be using a hash of your plaintext, which is why the result is shorter.

Edit: Heres the source for a [Rijndael Implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20120904015607/http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx).  It looks like the ciphertext output is initially the same length as the plaintext input, and then they do a base64 on it, which, as the previous poster mentioned, would reduce your final output to 3/4 of the original input.

Answer (score 0):

No, no idea at all, but my first thought would be that your encryption algorithm is built such that it removes 1 bit per 10 from the output data.

Only you can know for sure since we cannot see you code from out here :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a pretty lousy encryption algorithm if it was just replacing bytes one-for-one.  That was state of the art 50 years ago, and [it didn't work very well even then](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cryptanalysis_of_the_Enigma). :)